# How to use MOQ in crud operations

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, mocking, moq

I am having the a typical CRUD operation interface (repository) and i was wondering how would someone test it using `MOQ`.

**Model**

```
public class Model
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface ICrud
{
   Task<IEnumerable<Model>> GetAllAsync();
   Task AddAsync(Model model);
}
```

**Service**

```
public class Service
{
   public ICrud operations;

   Service(ICrud crud){ this.operations=crud;}

   public Task<IEnumerable<Model>> GetAllAsync()=>this.operations.GetAllAsync();
   public Task AddAsync(Model model)=> this.operations.AddAsync(model);
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
public class Test
{
   public IEnumerable Seed(){
        yield return new Model {id=3};
        yield return new Model {id =4};
   }
   [Testcase(3)]
   public async Task CanAdd(int id)
   {
         var mock=new Mock<ICrud>();
         var newModel=new Model{ Id=id};
         mock.Setup(x=>x.GetAsync()).ReturnsAsync(Seed);
         mock.Setup(x=>x.AddAsync(newModel));
        //how can i test adding the new model

         var service=new Service(mock.Object);
         var initialList=await service.GetAllAsync();
         //adding
         await service.AddAsync(newModel);
         var finalList=await service.GetAllAsync();

   }
}
```

My question is , how can i test the following scenario:

```
-i check the initial collection
-i call `AddAsync`
-i check to see that the new collection contains the added element.
```

How can this be achieved with `Moq` in a unit test?

Comment: The scenario you want to test is not unit testing. It's called integration testing and that requires you to have persistent storage and real data. You can not test this using mocks.

Comment: So you are telling me that a `Read your own writes` (`insert` + `getall` afterwards) scenario in which you use a mock as a database is not unit testing ?

Comment: In unit testing you should test the code paths of class via public methods in isolation.

Comment: If you want to test if `AddAsync` stores the data properly and `GetAllAsync` returns the collection with newly added object, then should really test write the integration test of class which implements `ICurd` interface. If you are writing unit tests of service class then you should test only service class code without worrying about testing its dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can do it without mocking frameworks.

```
public class InMemoryCrud : ICrud
{
    public List<Model> Models { get; set; } = new List<Model>();

    public Task<IEnumerable<Model>> GetAllAsync() => return Task.FromResult(Models);        

    public Task AddAsync(Model model)
    {
        Models.Add(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public async Task Add_Model() 
{
    var fakeCrud = new InMemoryCrud();
    var service = new Service(fakeCrud);

    var newModel = new Model { Id = 3 };
    await service.AddAsync(newModel);


    var actualModels = await fakeCrud.GetAllAsync();
    var expected = new[]
    {
        new Model { Id = 3 }
    }

    actualModels.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected); // Pass
}
```

With `InMemoryCrud` implementation you can test that correct values ahs been "saved" via crud operations.
With mocking frameworks you will test that correct methods has been called. For example if in `Service` class I change some properties of the given instance of the `Model` - tests still pass, but wrong data will be saved to the database in real application.

Comment: Yes i alredy tried that but i thought that using MOQ would ease the dependency creation process.But if you can not test multiple actions then yes your implementations is what i need.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, pass case is that the subject service under test correctly invokes the dependency operation with the given model.

The test should thus reflect that when being exercised.

Using MOQ that would look like

```
public async Task Service_Should_AddAsync() {
    //Arrange
    int id = 1;
    var mock = new Mock<ICrud>();
    var newModel = new Model { Id = id };
    mock.Setup(x => x.AddAsync(It.IsAny<Model>())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

    var service = new Service(mock.Object);

    //Act
    await service.AddAsync(newModel);

    //Assert
    //verify that the mock was invoked with the given model.
    mock.Verify(x => x.AddAsync(newModel));

}
```

Comment: I thought that as long as you do not require external dependencies like a database a connection etc its all in the realm of unit testing.I thought that calling 2 methods of the same construct(in my case the service  , whose dependency is mocked)  that you are testing is still unit testing.

Comment: Mocks are mocks as their name indicates. And you can setup the mock they way you want. That does not test any code of the real implementation of mocked entity. You can mock `AddSync` method to add entity and then mock `GetAllAsync` method to return nothing.....